# Use vb to add item and change value of second column of listview in wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

This is the xaml of listview

```
    <ListView Grid.Column="1" Height="auto" Name="ListView1" Width="auto" AllowDrop ="True" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="File Name" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Path" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="type" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I add a item into the listbox, but it add a row with three same value

```
    ListView1.Items.Add("abcd")
```

I have also tried some ways, but still have problem

So I would like to know how I can add different value to second column

```
    Dim x As ItemCollection
    x.Add("a")
    x.Add("b")
    x.Add("c")
    ListView1.Items.Add(x)

    Dim x As New ItemCollection
    x.Add("a")
    x.Add("b")
    x.Add("c")
    ListView1.Items.Add(x)
```

And How to get the value at second column?

I have tried this code, but it just return the second character of first column, I can't find any ways to access the second column

```
    ListView1.Items(0)(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to bind the list for this to work.

I made this sample class:

```
Public Class ListViewItemTemplate
    Public Property FileName As String
    Public Property FilePath As String
    Public Property FileType As String
End Class
```

Changed the xaml to include DisplayMember bindings:

```
    <ListView Name="ListView1" Width="auto" AllowDrop ="True" Margin="0,0,0,41">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView >
                <GridViewColumn Header="File Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Path" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FilePath}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="type" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FileType}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

And loaded some sample data:

```
    Dim itemsList As New List(Of ListViewItemTemplate)
    Dim item As New ListViewItemTemplate
    item.FileName = "FileName A"
    item.FilePath = "FilePath A"
    item.FileType = "FileType A"
    itemsList.Add(item)
    item = New ListViewItemTemplate
    item.FileName = "FileName B"
    item.FilePath = "FilePath B"
    item.FileType = "FileType B"
    itemsList.Add(item)
    item = New ListViewItemTemplate
    item.FileName = "FileName C"
    item.FilePath = "FilePath C"
    item.FileType = "FileType C"
    itemsList.Add(item)
    ListView1.ItemsSource = itemsList
```

Good luck!!